# Starting the Command Promt from a program using 'system(...)'

Tags: c, cmd

If I start the Command Prompt the Standard" way, go to 'C:\Windows\System32' and do "dir m*.exe", I get "several screensful" of listing. Among others 'msg.exe' is there. And if I do 'msg /?' :

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>msg /?
MSG {username | sessionname | sessionid | @filename | *}
  [/SERVER:servername] [/TIME:seconds] [/V] [/W] [message]
```

e
tc.

And the 'msg' command works as expected.

But if I start the Command Prompt from a program, with the 'system(...)' function, i.e. like this (Console application in Visual Studio):

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdlib.h>


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  system("cmd") ;
  return 0;
}
```

'msg' does not work:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>msg /?
'msg' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
```

operable program or batch file.

And `dir m*.exe` in this Command Prompt gives only half a screen of listing. Especially, `msg.exe` is not there.

Somebody who can explain why? Somebody who knows a walk-around? Or (even better) how I can do 'msg' from a program? I.e.

```
system("msg * /server:undis "Directory 'expenses' synced") ;
```

I would embed it in a program run via "Program after / When changes are made" in SyncBack Pro (2BrightSparks).

Comment: You must be building a 32 bit program. msg is only available in 64 bit mode.

Answer (score 0):

As n.m. comments, most likely the problem is that you're building a 32-bit program so the `cmd` you run with `system` is the 32-bit cmd emulator and not the nomral win64 cmd program.

This is what leads to your problem -- whenever you try to access C:\WINDOWS\system32 in 32-bit mode, the system silently sends you to C:\WINDOWS\sysWOW64 instead.  That's because on win64, `system32` actually contains 64-bit programs and dlls, not 32-bit ones.  The 32-bit ones are in sysWOW64.

Now normally this isn't an issue -- most of what you want in the 32-bit program is in sysWOW64, so everything is fine.  The problem is that `msg` is not.  So to get around that, you need to "escape" from the 32-bit sandbox.  To do that, you need to go to C:\WINDOWS\sysnative.  This directory (which is only available/visible in 32-bit mode) silently redirects to the (real, 64-bit) C:\WINDOWS\system32 directory.  If you cd to that directory, you should see msg.exe and be able to run it.  Or just run it directly from your system command:

```
system("C:\\WINDOWS\\sysnative\\msg * /server:undis "Directory 'expenses' synced") ;
```